# Make editor required for post from frontend

Tags: forms

I am trying to build a content submission form on the front end of my site, and I am using `wp_editor` to render visual text editors for my users, so they can make bold text and lists and stuff like that. The issue is that I can't figure out how to make the wp_editor a required field in my form. I know I can do the following for a standard text area.

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" required="required"></textarea>
```

that will make the browser itself recognize that it is a required field. No JavaScript jQuery or anything else needed. I need to accomplish the same thing with wp_editor, which does generate a textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter to the editor html

```
add_filter( 'the_editor', 'add_required_attribute_to_wp_editor', 10, 1 );

function add_required_attribute_to_wp_editor( $editor ) {
    $editor = str_replace( '<textarea', '<textarea required="required"', $editor );
    return $editor;
}
```

Comment: An invalid form control with name='subtitle' is not focusable.
I got above error.